# I am getting Component Load Failure error while using the local workbench in my hosted SP site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am following below GitHub sample for Image Carousel.

[Image Carousel Sample](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-carousel)

The code is compiling and building without any error. When I am trying to do gulp serve and trying to use the webpart in my hosted SP site in workbench mode. I am getting below error. Kindly help me here. I am unable proceed here bow.

Error I am getting as below.

> Failed to load component "d31b3bc5-4da5-4bf4-8d04-c14744eb5f13"
> (ImageCarouselWebPart). Original error: Manifest not found for
> component id "0d910c1c-13b9-4e1c-9aa4-b008c5e42d7d" and version
> "16.14.0".

Answer (score 0):

This error probably means that you are somehow using react version 16.14.0 that may not be compatible with SPFx version you are using. See the compatibility matrix [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility#spfx-development-environment-compatibility). The expected one for this sample is 16.8.5

The actual issue, however, may be the tooling version. The sample you are referring to was created around three years ago. So, for simplicity, you could just use the tooling from that time, i.e. node 10.x. There is a great [node version manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) aka NVM tool that allows you to use multiple independent node versions.

To successfully run this sample, you could try node 10.24.1:

```
> node --version
v10.24.1
> npm ci
> npm i -g gulp-cli
> gulp serve
```

Comment: For SPFx, the recommendation is to install gulp-cli at the global level instead of gulp. This can prevent incompatibility errors between the global version of gulp and the local version installed by SPFx. The latest version of gulp-cli is compatible with all versions of SPFx back to v1.0.  Change the third command to 
"npm i -g gulp-cli"

Comment: @DonKirkham which version of gulp-cli should be used? To make that sample compile? I've tested the code above before posting. If you could suggest a better one, please pick the exact version (and make sure that sample works with it), I'll change to it

Comment: @DonKirkham the latest works fine, changed! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I have below versions
@microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.15.2
react@16.14.0
npm -v 6.14.11
node -v v16.17.0

I see react 16.14.0 is in compatible, so tied installing react@16.13.1

but getting below error 'UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.13.1'

Comment: The easiest way to run the sample is to use the environment in which the sample was created, as in the answer above - then it works (use node 10, that is). If you don't do that but do something else instead, then you are on your own, and you have to upgrade the dependencies, this is not a trivial task. In particular, react@16.14.0 is the thing that is causing the first error in the question. Use a compatible react version at least.